# Flex textArea remove/replace invalid little squares

Tags: apache-flex, replace, flex4, textarea

This is related to my previous Flex issue:

[Flex TextArea - copy/paste from Word - Invalid unicode characters on xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905054/flex-textarea-copy-paste-from-word-invalid-unicode-characters-on-xml-parsing)

But this is slightly different & seems to be the issue. So I had to create another thread for this.

When I copy/paste text from word to a text area, I do not see any invalid characters. But when I pasted the same text on this url:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/07/preventing-line-feeds-in-a-textarea-control-in-flex/

I'm seeing a little square " ". Please paste this text into the URL:

> ```
> Bring the user base between the two applications into sync.
>  
> 2.    Requirements
> ```

and you should be able to see the same. Now I want to remove this invalid character/symbol. Is there any way to do it. I think this is the problem for my xml parser issue.

Thanks

Comment: I always thought such odd characters were line breaks, or some other "odd" character.  Word adds a lot of odd characters in copy/paste because it tries to maintain the format.  I suspect most of us won't know what your previous issue is and how this question relates to it.  By removing the line between the '.' and '2' you will not see the square box when pasting; so there is some "hidden character" there.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the related issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/133840/www-flextras-com : I just want to remove that hidden character. Any ideas please?

Comment: I don't think you meant to post a link to my profile. ;)

Comment: oops! was meant to be a shoutout :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to handle it by using the textArea changingHandler to allow only certain characters:

```
    if (event.operation is PasteOperation)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var txt:String = Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT).
                            toString().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s$%&*!@-_().]/ig, "");
                 ......
        }
```